# When using RTMFP to facilitate P2P, many-to-many live video chat, when should you use RTMFP groups?

Tags: flash, actionscript, streaming, flash-media-server, rtmfp

Basically I'm working on a program that facilitates many-to-many live video chat through RTMFP, falling back on RTMP.  I've already gotten all the basic functionality up and running, and people are able to come in and out and talk to each other just fine, for the most part.  However I'm coming across something called "groups" with RTMFP, which makes me think this may have been coded the wrong way.

When should you use NetGroup objects and stuff like that, and when should you just use your own concoction of P2P RTMFP (namely for live video chat)?  Does the desire to be able to fall back on RTMP do anything to influence this decision?  I know it might be a bad idea to go back and re-write all that, but I still need to really understand what I'm looking at here and when to use it.  Thanks!

EDIT: I am trying to keep some fairly specific tabs on individual visitors' connections, data related to the user but not streaming, etc.